# Browser History back() Method decreases minicart quantity

Tags: cache, varnish, block-cache, browser, history

We have discovered an interesting phenomenon with browsers history.
When I add some products from several product pages to the basket then the minicart at top will always update and shows me the current quantity of products in it.
But now when I decided to go some pages back with the browser back button (no matte if it is Firefox or Chrome) the minicart will decrease the quantity each time to that state before I put products into the basket.
 1. Product page 1 --> add 1 product in basket - in total 1
 2. Product page 2 --> add 1 product in basket - in total 2
 3. Product page 3 --> add 1 product in basket - in total 3
So when I go back in browser history to the second product I choosed before then my minicart suddenly displays 2 products in minicart.

When I click on the minicart to go to the cart directly then I have all 3 products.
It is only connected to browser history.

Since two days I can't find a reason why this happens.

We use Varnish 3 but we have added an esi cache-policy to exclude the minicart block from varnish caching.

And the shop is the latest Enterprise version 1.14.7.
I couldn't find any issues at github also.

Comment: If you, let's say access your homepage with an empty cart, then navigate to a product page and add the item and after that access the home page again, is your minicart count 0 or 1?

Comment: The minicart works correct if I go straight forward.
So in your case it will show 1.